# SSIS: Read property from another component?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I created a simple `SSIS` job that exports a sql table to a text file. Since the filename's dynamic, I set the `ConnectionString` in the `Flat File Connection Manager` to an expression. So that works fine and the text file's generated based on the expression.

Now, I need to email that file. Is it possible to access the `ConnectionString` property from another component?

I understand that I can use variables, but I don't want to write code for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the same expression in the other component?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an expression in multiple components you have to store it in a variable.

Create an SSIS variable, change the variable `Evaluate As Expression` property to True and write the expression in the variable `Expression` property.

Then in each component just use this variable as `Expression`

*Or just write the same expression in each component*